# .NET MAUI. Android. Scrolling of listview items is not available for physical keyboard

Tags: android, .net, keyboard, maui

I write application for Android TV and need to select listview items using buttons of remote control. Keyboard works fine on Windows build, but no reaction on Android. Had anyone faced with similar issue and has relative solution?